# Do XHR requests issued from Chrome extensions have the same browser fingerprint as XHRs issued from web pages?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, fingerprinting

If you issue an XHR HTTP request from a chrome browser extension background.js file to a 3rd party website (any website), will that request have the same browser fingerprint as XHR requests issued from any given webpage in the same browser?

Comment: It can be different (e.g. method POST will add Origin) but you can make it the same by using chrome.webRequest to modify your own xhr.

Comment: so assuming that both XHRs are equal in terms of URI, method, body, etc., then any receiving web server endpoint would determine that both requests carry the same fingerprint, on examination?